# Getting audio markers / cue points with the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, wav, web-audio-api, cue-points

If I have an audio file in WAV format containing markers (or "cue points"), is there a way to get an array of those markers, preferably using the Web Audio API?

I seem to remember seeing a method to do so before, but I can't seem to find it.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I stumbled across [a repository which supports the retrieval of cue markers](https://github.com/rochars/wavefile), along with a ton of other useful functionality. It works perfectly for what I was trying to do:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "file.wav", true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        var wave = new WaveFile(new Uint8Array(this.response));
        console.log(wave.listCuePoints()); // Works perfectly
    }
};
request.send();
```

It works on the browser as well as on Node.js, which is fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Web Audio API doesn't support parsing marker chunks (`"cue "`s) in WAVE-RIFF, only the audio data itself.

You'll have to parse and extract the marker chunks manually using for example typed arrays and [DataView](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/dataview) after loading the file as ArrayBuffer (unrelated to Web Audio API per-se).

It's a bit broad for giving a solution, but [this article](http://bleepsandpops.com/post/37792760450/adding-cue-points-to-wav-files-in-c) should be able to point you in the right direction as to how.